# Express server returns empty string as a response for proxied requests in Vite

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, vite

The request from frontend to backend is proxied successfully. The server fetches and logs the expected data. But the frontend logs empty string despite the backend returning the exact data logged.

Backend Code:

```js
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('working'))

app.get('/current', async (req, res) => {
  const { lat, lon } = req.query

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${process.env.API_KEY}`
    )
    console.log(response.data) //logs expected data
    res.json(response.data)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
    res.json(e)
  }
})
```

Frontend code:

```js
const { data } = useSWRV(
    () => `/api/current?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`,
    async key => {
      const res = await axios.get(key)
      console.log(res.data) //logs empty string
      return res.data
    }
  )
```

ViteConfig.ts

```js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        forward: 'http://localhost:8000',
        secure: false,
        ws: true,
        rewrite: path => path.replace('api', ''),
      },
    },
  },
})
```

I tried sending a request to `http://localhost:8000` directly without proxying which resulted in a CORS error (Missing allowed origin).
No error message is logged when using proxy.

Comment: Are you able to see the response in the console?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara In backend or frontend? As for the backend, the data is successfully fetched from the weather API. Where as for the frontend, res.data is an empty string even though response itself has status code of 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. Changing `forward: 'http://localhost:8000'` to `target: 'http://localhost:8000'` solved the problem.